# Why is the naming meaning of Compound DC Motors?

Tags: motor, dc

Why is the Cumulative Compound DC Motor called Cumulative and why is the Differential called Differential?

Comment: Differential as used where? maths, motor vehicle, amplifier?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_motor  Compound motors what is the reason behind their names

Comment: which differential are you talking about???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to ask, why is the Cumulative Compound DC Motor called
>   Cumulative and why is the Differential called Differential?

A compound DC motor has two field windings. These are called: -

- The series winding
- The shunt winding

The effects of one winding can be cancelled (or enhanced) by the other: -

[image]

Image taken from [this](http://slideplayer.com/slide/9185490/) slide player.

You can get various torque and speed versus loading effects by operating differentially or cumulatively: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.yourelectrichome.com/2011/10/characteristics-of-dc-compound-motor.html)

Comment: This doesn't explain why they are called the way they are called, I knew this part already

Comment: @ErezD I used the word "enhanced" and "cancelled" in my answer. Did you understand that cumulative means enhanced and differential means cancelled in this type of motor. The fields are added or in opposition and this produces various effects as shown in my diagram at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer or raise another comment @ErezD